# Aligning text in golang with Truetype

Tags: go, truetype

I am trying to render some text on a png in a Golang project using freetype/truetype. As you can see from the attachment, I am trying to render 4 letters in columns - each letter centered in the column. Have used the truetype api to get bounds and widths of the glyphs but have been unable to convert these to give me an accurate offset for each glyph. For example with the `O` glyph, given the font I using. I get the following dimensions:

`Hmetric {AdvanceWidth:543 LeftSideBearing:36}
Bounds {XMin:0 YMin:-64 XMax:512 YMax:704}
Advance width: 512`

With the last dimension being returned from [GlyphBuf](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/freetype-go/freetype/truetype#GlyphBuf).

I rendered it using the following:

`size := 125.00
tileOffset := (int(tileWidth) * i) + int(tileWidth/2)
pt := freetype.Pt(tileOffset, (imgH-newCharHeight)-int(size))`

How can I use the glyph dimensions returned by truetype to offset the letters correctly? I have tried using the `AdvanceWidth` as detailed [in this plotinum](https://code.google.com/p/plotinum/source/browse/vg/font.go) code (line 160) but that does not give me a consistent result across all glyphs.

[image: Example of rendering]

Comment: Heh... funnily enough we were looking at this at my work last week. Each font has ascent and descent properties... overhang/underhang, etc. Basically, you need an API that gives you dimensions without the ascent.. so you can position it properly. Have a play with the `Extents` method in that API and the Ascent and Descent properties. I will provide a proper answer when I get a break today

Comment: Apoplogies - my terminology is off - Ascent and Descent relate to vertical positioning .. what you need is the Advance or Bounds of each character. I don't suppose you could share a full snippet using the `AdvanceWidth`?

Answer (score 12):

As suggested by Simon the correct solution is to use AdvanceWidth:

[image]

Crude example:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "image"
    "bufio"
    "image/draw"
    "image/png"
    "image/color"
    "github.com/golang/freetype/truetype"
    "golang.org/x/image/font"
    "github.com/golang/freetype"
    "os"
)

var (
    dpi      = flag.Float64("dpi", 72, "screen resolution in Dots Per Inch")
    fontfile = flag.String("fontfile", "/usr/share/fonts/liberation/LiberationSerif-Regular.ttf", "filename of the ttf font")
    hinting  = flag.String("hinting", "none", "none | full")
    size     = flag.Float64("size", 125, "font size in points")
    spacing  = flag.Float64("spacing", 1.5, "line spacing (e.g. 2 means double spaced)")
    wonb     = flag.Bool("whiteonblack", false, "white text on a black background")
    text     = string("JOJO")
)


func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    fmt.Printf("Loading fontfile %q\n", *fontfile)
    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(*fontfile)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    f, err := truetype.Parse(b)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }

    // Freetype context
    fg, bg := image.Black, image.White
    rgba := image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, 1000, 200))
    draw.Draw(rgba, rgba.Bounds(), bg, image.ZP, draw.Src)
    c := freetype.NewContext()
    c.SetDPI(*dpi)
    c.SetFont(f)
    c.SetFontSize(*size)
    c.SetClip(rgba.Bounds())
    c.SetDst(rgba)
    c.SetSrc(fg)
    switch *hinting {
    default:
        c.SetHinting(font.HintingNone)
    case "full":
        c.SetHinting(font.HintingFull)
    }

    // Make some background

    // Draw the guidelines.
    ruler := color.RGBA{0xdd, 0xdd, 0xdd, 0xff}
    for rcount := 0; rcount < 4; rcount ++ {
        for i := 0; i < 200; i++ {
            rgba.Set(250*rcount, i, ruler)
        }
    }

    // Truetype stuff
    opts := truetype.Options{}
    opts.Size = 125.0
    face := truetype.NewFace(f, &opts)


    // Calculate the widths and print to image
    for i, x := range(text) {
        awidth, ok := face.GlyphAdvance(rune(x))
        if ok != true {
            log.Println(err)
            return
        }
        iwidthf := int(float64(awidth) / 64)
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", iwidthf)

        pt := freetype.Pt(i*250+(125-iwidthf/2), 128)
        c.DrawString(string(x), pt)
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", awidth)
    }


    // Save that RGBA image to disk.
    outFile, err := os.Create("out.png")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer outFile.Close()
    bf := bufio.NewWriter(outFile)
    err = png.Encode(bf, rgba)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    err = bf.Flush()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Println("Wrote out.png OK.")


}
```

Comment: Is it possible in Go to calculate the Ascent/Descent or a Bounding Rectangle for a string rendered in a truetype font?

Comment: Thanks for good example. Can you explain these two lines:
`iwidthf := int(float64(awidth) / 64)` and `pt := freetype.Pt(i*250+(125-iwidthf/2), 128)` - what are the constants there?